# How to efficiently deal with nested data in PySpark?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I had a situation here, and found that collect_list in spark is not efficient when the item is already a list.

Basically, I tried to calculate the mean of a nested list (the size of each list is guaranteed to be the same). When the data set becomes, for example, 10 M rows, it may produce out of memory errors. Originally, I thought it has something to do with the udf (to calculate the mean). But actually, I found that the aggregation part (collect_list of lists) is the real problem.

What I am doing now is to divide the 10 M rows into multiple blocks (by 'user'), aggregate each block individually, and then union them at the end. Any better suggestion on efficiently dealing with nested data?

For example, the toy example is like this:

```
data = [('user1','place1', ['place1', 'place2', 'place3'], [0.0, 0.5, 0.4], [0.0, 0.4, 0.3]),
    ('user1','place2', ['place1', 'place2', 'place3'], [0.7, 0.0, 0.4], [0.6, 0.0, 0.3]),
    ('user2','place1', ['place1', 'place2', 'place3'], [0.0, 0.4, 0.3], [0.0, 0.3, 0.4]),
    ('user2','place3', ['place1', 'place2', 'place3'], [0.1, 0.2, 0.0], [0.3, 0.1, 0.0]),
    ('user3','place2', ['place1', 'place2', 'place3'], [0.3, 0.0, 0.4], [0.2, 0.0, 0.4]),
   ]
data_df = sparkApp.sparkSession.createDataFrame(data, ['user', 'place', 'places', 'data1', 'data2'])

data_agg = data_df.groupBy('user') \
    .agg(f.collect_list('place').alias('place_list'),
         f.first('places').alias('places'),
         f.collect_list('data1').alias('data1'),
         f.collect_list('data1').alias('data2'),
        )

import numpy as np
def average_values(sim_vectors):
    if len(sim_vectors) == 1:
        return sim_vectors[0]
    mat = np.array(sim_vectors)
    mean_vector = np.mean(mat, axis=0)
    return np.round(mean_vector, 3).tolist()

avg_vectors_udf = f.udf(average_values, ArrayType(DoubleType()))
data_agg_ave = data_agg.withColumn('data1', avg_vectors_udf('data1')) \
    .withColumn('data2', avg_vectors_udf('data2'))
```

The result would be:

```
+-----+----------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+

| user|      place_list|              places|            data1|            data2|

+-----+----------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+

|user1|[place1, place2]|[place1, place2, ...|[0.35, 0.25, 0.4]|[0.35, 0.25, 0.4]|

|user3|        [place2]|[place1, place2, ...|  [0.3, 0.0, 0.4]|  [0.3, 0.0, 0.4]|

|user2|[place1, place3]|[place1, place2, ...|[0.05, 0.3, 0.15]|[0.05, 0.3, 0.15]|

+-----+----------------+--------------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: What Spark version are you using ? `pandas_udf` might help if you're using Spark 2.3

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, good idea, will try and update this